# How to convert LiveData<List<Foo>> into LiveData<List<Bar>>?

Tags: android, android-livedata

Let's say we have two objects of LiveData:

```
LiveData<List<Foo>> fooList;
LiveData<List<Bar>> barList;
```

And by some method (or the constructor) Foo can be converted to the Bar object.
What is the best way to convert the first observable, which has the list of Foo objects to the observable with the list of Bar objects.

I know that it is possible to do this:

```
barList = Transformations.map(fooList, fooList1 -> {
        List<Bar> barList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Foo foo: fooList1) {
            barList.add(new Bar(foo)); 
        }
        return barList;
    });
```

But isn't there a better way similar to the flatMap operator in RxJava, by which we make all of the necessary conversions with the items from the list on the fly instead of dealing with the lists themselves as in the example above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own transformation, following the recipe shown in the source to `Transformations`. FWIW, [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-androidarch/tree/v0.2/General/LiveFilter) demonstrates a custom `filter()` implementation:

```
/***
 Copyright (c) 2017 CommonsWare, LLC
 Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
 use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
 of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
 by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
 License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
 OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
 language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

 Covered in detail in the book _Android's Architecture Components_
 https://commonsware.com/AndroidArch
 */

package com.commonsware.android.livedata;

import android.arch.lifecycle.LiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData;
import android.arch.lifecycle.Observer;
import android.support.annotation.MainThread;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;

class LiveTransmogrifiers {
  interface Confirmer<T> {
    boolean test(T thingy);
  }

  @MainThread
  static <X> LiveData<X> filter(@NonNull LiveData<X> source,
                                @NonNull final Confirmer<X> confirmer) {
    final MediatorLiveData<X> result=new MediatorLiveData<>();

    result.addSource(source, new Observer<X>() {
      @Override
      public void onChanged(@Nullable X x) {
        if (confirmer.test(x)) {
          result.setValue(x);
        }
      }
    });

    return(result);
  }
}
```

Otherwise, no. `LiveData` is meant as a lightweight RxJava analogue that is lifecycle-aware. If you need lots of operators, you are better served using RxJava directly.

Comment: I still don't understand by your example how it can help to deal with the elements of the list instead of the whole list itself. That is, in the code you mentioned, in OnChanged function, for my case there will be the List of elements instead of just one element and I will have to do all the same which I did in the Transformations.map code above.

Comment: @AlexeyTimokhin: You would need to look to see how RxJava implements `flatMap()`. Then, see if you can create an equivalent `LiveData` transformation. Perhaps it is not possible. In that case, the final paragraph of my answer still holds.

Comment: @CommonsWare why not SwitchMap? I will come on that today with you  in the chat hours on your site

Comment: @trocchietto: I probably was forgetting that `switchMap()` existed when I wrote the answer. I'm not 100% certain that it would cover the OP's scenario, but it might.

Comment: Ok will ask you today at your 4pm. Thanks