# Android LiveData transformations

Tags: android, retrofit2, rx-java2, android-livedata

I have a simple class

```
public class Contacts {
    public ArrayList<Contact> items;
}
```

I have a retrofit get request

```
LiveData<ApiResponse<Contacts>> getContacts();
```

which returns `LiveData<ApiResponse<Contacts>>` but I need to use it further as a list of items `LiveData<ApiResponse<List<Contact>>>`

```
protected LiveData<ApiResponse<List<Contact>>> createCall() {
  LiveData<ApiResponse<Contacts>> contacts = apiService.getContacts();

  return contacts.items;
}
```

So question is how to convert one livedata into another livedata ?

Comment: If this were converting `LiveData<Contacts>` into `LiveData<List<Contact>>`, you could use `Transformations.map()`. I don't know what `ApiResponse` is, though.

Comment: Maybe this could help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46040027/how-to-convert-livedatalistfoo-into-livedatalistbar

Answer (score 0):

Use [Transformations](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata) to convert one LiveData into another.

```
LiveData<User> userLiveData = ...;
LiveData<String> userName = Transformations.map(userLiveData, user -> {
    user.name + " " + user.lastName
});
```

For your case, use something like this

```
LiveData<List<Contact>> contactList = Transformations.map(contactsLiveData, it -> {
    it.contacts() // returns list
});
```